# How Filter $emit on Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

How can I **catch** emitted event and change value **without create a new data flow**?

> I designed to make it easier to understand: http://prntscr.com/pk4kid

---

***Edit:***

I use vue-form-generator to generate dynamic forms, but when it is file, I need to go to the server and use only the variable, otherwise the weight of the files freezes the browser...

> This is the event emitted from vue-form-generator http://prntscr.com/pk5y6o

Comment: with catch you mean intercept? first thought is to override emit function. pls also add an on page example snipped - thx

Comment: It might be better to provide a reason for this idea. Why would you need to modify this emitted event?

Comment: I try use the watch function on the array, but don't work. This is the array http://prntscr.com/pk6tu9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solved my problem:

```
  watch: {
    list: {
      deep: true,

      // We have to move our method to a handler field
      handler() {
        console.log("The list of colours has changed!");
      }
    }
  }
```